# How to attach documents in ms access using vb6

Tags: ms-access, vb6

Good day. I have an Access database with a field using an attachment data type. Is there a way to use Visual Basic 6 to attach my documents, such as images, Word files and PDF files on that database? Specifically on the field using the attachment data type.

Comment: What is an "attachment data type"? A blob with the actual file Contents? A string description (like mime codes)? A string containing the Extension? A numeric field filled from enum?

Comment: Probably one of the weird SharePoint oriented extensions that was added by ACE.  I cringe to think anyone uses this stuff in real applications.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, from the LoadFromFile Method.

Snippet below:

```
Set AttachmentRecordset = RecordSetForTable.Fields("AttachmentFieldName").Value
FileName = "SomePathToAFile"    

AttachmentRecordset.AddNew
AttachmentRecordset.Fields("FileData").LoadFromFile (FileName)
AttachmentRecordset.Update
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan. by the way do you have sample program for that because i don't know how to start it.

Comment: Hi, the snippet is above that answers your question. SO, is intended for help and instruction, not to do it for you.